# Fast API with pytest using AsyncClient gives 422 on post?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fastapi, httpx

I'm trying to send a request to an api using **pytest** through **httpx.AsynClient**

```
@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_device_create_with_data(self, client, random_uuid):
    device_create = DeviceCreateFactory.build(subId=random_uuid)

    json = device_create.json(by_alias=True)

    response = await client.post("/device", json=json)

    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Client fixture:

```
from httpx import AsyncClient


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def client():
    async with AsyncClient(
            app=app,
            base_url="http://test/api/pc",
            headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    ) as client:
        yield client
```

API endpoint:

```
@device_router.post("/device", response_model=CommonResponse)
async def create_device(device: DeviceCreate):
    _, err = await crud_device.create_device(device)

    if err:
        return get_common_response(400, err)

    return get_common_response(200, "ok")
```

Schemas:

```
class DeviceBase(BaseModel):
    device_id: StrictStr = Field(..., alias='deviceId')
    device_name: StrictStr = Field(..., alias='deviceName')
    device_type: StrictStr = Field(..., alias='deviceType')
    age_mode: AgeModeType = Field(..., alias='ageMode')

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        validate_all = True
        validate_assignment = True


class DeviceCreate(DeviceBase):
    sub_id: StrictStr = Field(..., alias='subId')

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Factory:

```
from pydantic_factories import ModelFactory

from app.core.schemas.device import DeviceCreate


class DeviceCreateFactory(ModelFactory):
    __model__ = DeviceCreate
```

And i'm getting a **422** error with following response content:

```
"message":"bad request","details":{"deviceId":"field required","deviceName":"field required","deviceType":"field required","ageMode":"field required","subId":"field required"}
```

Then i examined the data of the request being sent and got:

```
b'"{\\"deviceId\\": \\"de\\", \\"deviceName\\": \\"\\", \\"deviceType\\": \\"\\", \\"ageMode\\": \\"child\\", \\"subId\\": \\"11aded61-9966-4be1-a781-387f75346811\\"}"'
```

Seems like everything is okay, but where is the trouble then?

I've tried to examine the request data in exception handler of 422
I've made:

```
@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):

    print(await request.json())

    response = validation_error_response(exc)
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content=jsonable_encoder(response.dict())
    )
```

But code after print is unreachable, because `await request.json()` never ends and runs forever trying to print a request json

Is there a way to manage this problem?
Thanks for any suggest!

P.S.

**python version:** 3.8.9

**fastapi version:** 0.68.1

**httpx version:** 0.21.1

Comment: What is the problem? is it `422` or `never ending process` ?

Comment: The problem in the test is 422. An endless process that I just noticed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're double encoding your content as JSON - you're both asking for it to be returned as a JSON string, and then telling your request method to encode it as JSON a second time. `json=` as an argument to the method on the client *converts* the given data to JSON - it does not expect already serialized JSON.

You can see this in your request string because it starts with `"` and not with `{` as you'd expect:

```
b'"{\
  ^
```

Instead build your model around a dictionary - or as I'd prefer in a test - build the request by hand, so that you're testing how you imagine an actual request should look like.

You can use `dict` in the same was as you'd use `json` for a Pydantic model:

```
device_create = DeviceCreateFactory.build(subId=random_uuid)

response = await client.post("/device", json=device_create.dict(by_alias=True))

assert response.status_code == 200
```